# "Present continuous "or "going to" here

Tags: future-constructions

she **is working/going to work** in June and July as a nurse in a  hospital in Roma. She will be helping old people .She found this job yesterday.

Can I use present continuous in this case? It is a future event so it should be . I think present continuous  is better than going to because it is not an  intention it has become an arrangement now

Comment: Either would be acceptable.

Comment: I would only use present continuous here if I also specified when the job starts, because otherwise it sounds like she's working there right now. It's not like "I'm going to China" where it's clear you're not going this instant.

Comment: so as I have specified  the months  she will be working present continuous is valid

Comment: Are you familiar with the function of present continuous to mean future plans?

Comment: I think so it must be certain and to be not too far

Answer (score 0):

You can but depending on the relativity of the specified date, using present continuous could be confusing.

For example, consider if:

1. it is currently June and "she is working in June and July as a nurse". This works very well.
2. it is currently March and "she is working in June and July as a nurse". Okay this still works fine
3. it is currently 2022 and "she is working in June 2040 as a nurse". This is a lot stranger but the only thing that's changed is how far off it is from now.

In all of these scenarios above, "she is going to work in  as a nurse" work very well. Similarly so for "she will be working".

Also because things may change overtime, while "I will be working some job 10 years from now" is *correct*, one may prefer to indicate the present "plan" for the future to account for change overtime like "she plans to work in" or "she is planning to work in" which *is* present continuous and works because she is planning *now* to *then* be working whereas "is working" implies *now* into the future.

Comment: in fact I wrote this text last year in May and she started her job  in June last year

Comment: Ah! so then yes I think it's totally appropriate in your context given that she 1) recently procured this job 2) will be starting very soon (less than 1 month when you're using months as the relative unit of time). I do think that "is going to" is still _better_ as your concern that the difference is in intention vs absolute doesn't really apply to "is going to" like it would to "plans to work". Right so "she is going to work" still implies that "it has become an arrangement now" and is **not** just an intention.